# Jenkins working directories vocabulary misundertanding [agent configuration]

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

In the agent configuration screens, Jenkins is talking about:

- Remote root directory
- Custom WorkDir path *(when you choose Java web Start JNLP)*
- Agent Root Directory *(when you choose Java web Start JNLP)*

I'm living a bad user experience, because I don't understand what I'm able to set.

What are this 3 directories? What will happen to it?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Root Directory - "An agent needs to have a directory dedicated to Jenkins. Specify the path to this directory on the agent. It is best to use an absolute path, such as /var/jenkins" The directory that you set here will become the Jenkins directory on the new agent that you are creating.

Custom WorkDir path - If defined, this will be a custom remoting work directory that will be used instead of the remote root directory defined above. Recommended to use absolute paths in this case.

Agent Root Directory - I believe that this is the same as the Remote root directory, I don't see it when I go to Java web Start JNLP. So definition wise I think it's the same as the Remote Root Directory.